# Tell iPadOS from macOS on the web

Tags: macos, safari, mobile-safari, user-agent, ipados

The user agent of Safari on iPadOS beta is at this point exactly the same as Safari on macOS. Is there any other way to tell an iPad from a Mac?

```
iPad running iOS
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1

iPadOS, developer beta 1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS, beta 2, simulator
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS, beta 3, (simulator)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS, developer beta 3
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS, developer beta 4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS 13.1, developer beta 1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS 13.1, developer beta 2
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS 13.1, developer beta 3
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15

iPadOS 13.1, developer beta 4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15

macOS Catalina 
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

macOS (older version)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15

macOS Catalina developer beta 7
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

macOS Catalina developer beta 8
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
```

When playing HLS video, the iPadOS agent seems to be:

```
AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.17A5821e (iPad; U; CPU OS 13_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually another case of "spoofing" mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7976057/129202

Comment: In Japanese, nonetheless https://qiita.com/m-otoguro/items/00602315724d4a8e580c

Comment: I added the user agent of next macOS Catalina. Note that it is **EXACTLY** the same as iPadOS.

Comment: I think you just can't ??? Currently my solution is, if user-agent shows 10.15, show a pop-up ask if is iPadOS or macOS.

Comment: Looking for a solution to this issue as well, and the only thing I can see that may be of use is this: 

Navigator.standalone

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator: "Returns a boolean indicating whether the browser is running in standalone mode. Available on Apple's iOS Safari only."

Trying to get a machine with macOS 10.15 to see if it returns a value on desktop safari, but on my 10.14 macOS safari it was undefined. Returned a value in 10.15 iOS/ipadOS in my simulator

Comment: Interesting thanks, will try on macOS 10.15 when I get time. But then again it sounds pretty fragile even if it would work now. If possible we should probably all treat iPads as desktops going forward.

Comment: @Jonny please update with your findings on macOS 10.15.. but I agree it's fragile, not the best solution

Comment: @Jonny a catalina 10.15 beta (from July 16, 2019) macOS safari version did not have the navigator.standalone.. so this feature detection may be of use. Maybe combine it with screen size detection? either way, I am still curious if your macOS 10.15 has navigator.standalone

Comment: @user2879041 A pretty recent Catalina returned `undefined` for `Navigator.standalone`.

Comment: @user2879041 iPadOS, developer beta 4 also returned `undefined` for `Navigator.standalone`.

Answer (score 46):

I'm using this test client side:

```
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac/) && navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2) {
     ...must be iPad OS...
```

Since there's no official touch screen for Mac, it seems pretty safe. The actual value of maxTouchPoints on the iPad is 5, BTW.

Comment: And to those who say it shouldn't matter (use fluid webdesign!) it does matter if the user needs to either install a Safari app/extension from the Mac Store or use the iOS Share extension. I need to provide the correct link and directions.

Comment: iPad emulation on Chrome only supports 1 maxTouchPoints, so unless you don't plan on debugging using Chrome I would suggest dropping the > 2 check.

Answer (score 13):

I would not generally recommend this, <s>and I haven't tested it much</s> (using something similar in production since September 2019), but one way could be to detect the existence of `TouchEvent` on the client side, and match it with the state of the user agent to account for older iOS versions of iPad:s. YMMV. Likely not very future safe.

```js
function isIpad() {
    const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf('iPad') > -1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (ua.indexOf('Macintosh') > -1) {
        try {
            document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
            return true;
        } catch (e) {}
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `isIpad()` returns true on Chrome 85 on MBP (Catalina) without touch

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this works fine:

```
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isiPad = ua.indexOf('ipad') > -1 || ua.indexOf('macintosh') > -1 && 'ontouchend' in document;
```

Comment: Checking only userAgent is NOT enough. Maybe `navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2` is a good enough stop-gap fix.

Answer (score 2):

as @Jonny mentioned you can try and detect touch events, this is the solution i currently use

```js
function isTouchDevice() {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return false
  const prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ')
  function mq(query) {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.matchMedia(query).matches
  }
  if ('ontouchstart' in window || (window?.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) return true
  const query = ['(', prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('), 'heartz', ')'].join('') // include the 'heartz' - https://git.io/vznFH
  return mq(query)
}
```

interesting post on [detecting touch events](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/)

and another note, Firefox on Ipad uses the same safari user-agent :/

Comment: `isTouchDevice()` (May 24th version) returns true on Chrome 85 on a MBP (Catalina) without touch. Maybe `navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2` is a good enough stop-gap fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ua-parser-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js) to parse the User-Agent, you will see that iPad has "Mobile Safari" as the `browser.name`, while Macs have "Safari".

If the user is logged in on Chrome, `parsedUA.device.model` will be `iPad` for iPad.

The only problem seems to be on Firefox... which has "Safari" as `browser.name` and "Macintosh" as `parsedUA.device.model` for iPad...

( I am trying to rely solely on User-Agent because I'm pulling user's logged-in devices from back-end and I have no other information about the user's device )