# Distinguish between iPad and mac on iPad with iPadOs

Tags: ios, ipad, user-agent, ios13, ipados

In iOS 13 apple changed the user-agent that iPad uses.

Instead of (for example)

> Mozilla/5.0(**iPad**; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10

it become (for example)

> Mozilla/5.0 (**Macintosh**; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

My question is how can we distinguish between iPad and mac now?

Comment: That's the point. You shouldn't. You should serve a desktop site to an iPad.

Comment: @Paulw11 but I have a serivce that is supported only on iPad and not mac!

Comment: Well, an iPad is now a Mac as far as web sites are concerned

Comment: Thanks but that’s not an answer to my question.

Comment: I understand that, I guess what I am saying is that barring any changes by Apple in subsequent betas is that you can no longer tell the difference between an iPad and a Mac from a web server; Apple don't want web servers to know. You might as well just support Macs since you already are; Changing user agent on Safari to look like an iPad is trivial.  I guess you could try and examine the window size, but that is pretty unreliable, especially since iPadOS will support even more flexible windowing.  If you really want iPad only, release an app

Comment: Even I have same issue. I want to show download .dmg in case of it's Mac & redirect it to app store if its IPadOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tell iPadOS from macOS on the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578799/tell-ipados-from-macos-on-the-web)

Comment: See my comment here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765958/how-to-detect-ipad-and-ipad-os-version-in-ios-13-and-up/57924983#57924983

Comment: @zvi Problem is, it still does not support all the features (like background-attachment: fixed).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The condition I used to detect IpadOS:

```
ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('macintosh') > -1 && navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately doing so via the User-Agent string alone doesn't seem to be possible anymore. This is a bit of an issue if you're server-side and need to share downloads differently as you mentioned in one of your comments.

However, the below should reliably detect iPads on the client-side:

```
const iPad = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)/)
  || (navigator.platform === "MacIntel" && typeof navigator.standalone !== "undefined"))
```

It avoids relying on touch events which will occur on Macs with touch screen monitors, and instead uses `navigator.standalone` which is an iOS **only** property.

Comment: We did try this, but it did not work to display data to iPad (6th generation) using `navigator.standalone` as a filter. Will be doing some more tests with this solution as well as `const iPad = (userAgent.match(/(iPad)/) /* iOS pre 13 */ || 
  (navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1) /* iPad OS 13 */);`.

Comment: @rhand testing on Browserstack 6th Gen iPads it works as expected, the older gen versions are usually easier to detect as they contain the string iPad within navigator.userAgent - what browser are you testing in?

Comment: Just using latest Safari 14.0.3. I think the issue may be that we load the check too late in our Vue file. We will need to do some more tests. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Combining quangh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59187672/7475250) and Michael Zaporozhets's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/7475250) to detect mobile devices including iPads.

```
detectMobile() {
  let isMobile = RegExp(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|iPad/i)
   .test(navigator.userAgent);

  if (!isMobile) {
    const isMac = RegExp(/Macintosh/i).test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isMac && navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2) {
      isMobile = true;
    }
  }
  return isMobile;
}
```